# roxygen2 is processing too many files

Tags: r, roxygen2

I have used R roxygen2 on Linux for many years, on packages whose R directories have a mixture of .s files and .r files.  The .s files do not use roxygen2 markup and the .r files do.  roxygen2::roxygenize() only processed the .r files and all was well.  Now on MacOS it is processing all files and throwing errors on the bad markup in the .s files.  How do I return to the previous behavior?  I'm using roxygen2 7.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted anything reproducible, so any answer will be speculation.  In a previous answer I speculated and I think I got it wrong, so I deleted that one.  Here's my current thinking:

You can't do what you are asking to do.

You say that you did this previously on Linux, and blame the change on using a Mac; but I think there must be other important differences besides the OS.  Roxygen probably has small platform-dependent differences, but I don't think there would be anything as big as what you describe.

I guessed that you were talking about the `Hmisc` package, and tried it myself.  I saw warnings like

```
areg.s:432: S3 method `plot.areg` needs @export or @exportS3method tag.
```

These warnings come when you ask `roxygenize()` to create the `NAMESPACE` file, and they are unavoidable.  For `plot.areg` to be treated as an S3 method, it should be mentioned in `NAMESPACE`.  In the `Hmisc` version I was looking at you had a hand-written `NAMESPACE` file that contained

```
S3method(plot,areg)
```

If you ask `roxygenize()` to create your `NAMESPACE` file, but you also ask it to ignore the `areg.s` file, how could it possibly know to add that line?

So your only solutions are to add markup to your `.s` files, or to stop asking `roxygenize()` to create the `NAMESPACE` file.  When I ran

```
roxygenize(roclets = "rd")
```

on `Hmisc`, everything was fine, and the hand-written `NAMESPACE` wasn't touched.

Comment: Thanks very much for this input.  Years of use of `roxygen2` on Linux without ever encountering this problem, even with the identical `NAMESPACE` setup tells me there is some kind of platform dependency that should be corrected.  But I’ll look more into your line of thinking.   Do you know right off hand how to tell `roxygenize` to fully respect the existing `NAMESPACE`?  I thought it did that automatically.

Comment: I would guess that what is new is giving warnings about S3 methods with no markup.  `roxygenize(roclet="namespace")` is probably written to do all the calculations, then abort if it detects a non-Roxygen `NAMESPACE` file. The warning was a new feature in 7.3.0; maybe on Linux you used an older version.  It just aborted without any fuss.

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this.  Running with `roclets='rd'` did the trick.